# match only the digits from percentage using regular expression

Tags: regex

Have a pandas dataframe, some of the cells contain percentage, taking a further look  each cell is like `'\u200b68%', '\u200b.75%','\u200b3.4%'`. Only want to match the digit out.
Tried `re.findall('(\d*(\.\d+)?)','\u200b.75%')` but got too many stuffs.
What I expected `68, .75, 3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the percentage sign after it, and use a single capturing group to be used with re.findall

```
(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)%
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vBbjP1/1)

If the `\u200b` part should be present, you could also match that:

```
\\u200b(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)%
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TBmrjK/1)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\\u200b(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)%"
test_str = ("\\u200b68%\n"
    "\\u200b.75%\n"
    "\\u200b3.4%")
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)

print(matches)
```

Output

```
['68', '.75', '3.4']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work..

```
\\u200b([0-9.]{1,5})%
```

Demo: https://paiza.io/projects/L9ZgArU-WZXxcRlGzVHH0Q